# Specify a Singleton service in a WCF self hosted service

Tags: wcf, self-hosting

I am writing an application that exposes a service via WCF. The service is self-hosted (console app) and needs to use a Singleton instance. I am trying to figure out how to specify singleton in the service configuration *without* using attributes on the service implementation. Is it possible to specify singleton in code without an attribute?

Thanks,
Erick

Answer (score 22):

<strike>You can pass instance of the service to the `ServiceHost` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx) instead of passing a type. In such case your passed instance will be used as singleton.</strike>

**Edit:**

My former solution doesn't work. Providing instance to `ServiceHost` constructor still demands `ServiceBehaviorAttribute` with `InstanceContextMode.Single`. But this one should work:

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
var behavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
host.Open();
```

`ServiceBehaviorAttribute` is included even if you don't specify it so you just need to get it and change default value.

Comment: I am new to WCF and I have a WCF service which I want to control with configuration instead of metadata on class. Could you please provide details of your solution.

Comment: I needed to force the `InstanceContextMode` to `PerCall`, and this method works for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move this into `web.config` or `app.config`, you could do so with a custom `BehaviorExtensionElement` and `IServiceBehavior`:

The `IServiceBehavior` will actually parse the value from config into the enum and set it (following @Ladislav's answer):

```
public class InstanceContextServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    InstanceContextMode _contextMode = default(InstanceContextMode);

    public InstanceContextServiceBehavior(string contextMode)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contextMode))
        {
            InstanceContextMode mode;

            if (Enum.TryParse(contextMode, true, out mode))
            {
                _contextMode = mode;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"'{contextMode}' Could not be parsed as a valid InstanceContextMode; allowed values are 'PerSession', 'PerCall', 'Single'", "contextMode");
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        var behavior = serviceDescription.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
        behavior.InstanceContextMode = _contextMode;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The extension element allows you to pull it from config and pass it to the `IServiceBehavior`:

```
public class InstanceContextExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(InstanceContextServiceBehavior);
        }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new InstanceContextServiceBehavior(ContextMode);
    }

    const object contextMode = null;

    [ConfigurationProperty(nameof(contextMode))]
    public string ContextMode
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base[nameof(contextMode)];
        }
        set
        {
            base[nameof(contextMode)] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can then register it in your config and use it:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="instanceContext" type="FULLY QUALFIED NAME TO CLASS"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
...
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Default">
      <instanceContext contextMode="Single"/>
```