# Can we move WCF contract to a separate config file?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to move the WCF Service contract to a separate configuration XML file, so that they can be modified on production, without having the need for redeployment.

To be specific, it is possible to move this code from .cs file to some other .xml file, which will allow me to modify the contract, post deployment.

*[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]*

Note: This is for a WinForms(Desktop) application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use XML includes or config references in app.config to include other config files' settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-file)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is different. Please see the edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813975/can-i-split-system-servicemodel-into-a-separate-config-file

Comment: Don't do this, it isn't a good idea.

Comment: You can do this, but you will have to write a custom extension to do so.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5787557/745969) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946709/745969).   Then you could use the `configSource` attribute in the `<extensions>` element of the application's config file to point to the config file that contains the extension info.   But that's a lot of work....